# ExtJs 6.7 - When in textarea and writing text, pressing TAB key does not exit textarea field

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a text area in a panel and after entering some text to it and pressing tab key, cursor does not exit field. It only leaves field on second press of TAB key. Anybody else experienced this?

here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/383o) example.

1. enter some text to text area field (3rd field)
2. press tab key

you will se that cursor is still in the textarea field.

Any help of how to make tab key leave field on first press, greatly appreciated.

Comment: In firefox, chrome and safari browsers it jumps to the first "test" button. After typing some text it jumps to the "test" button on the first tab button press. Which browser are you using?

Comment: tried chrome, firefox ... works the same .. you have to press TAB key twice to loose focus on text area field after you stop entering text ... meaning .. 
type something and press TAB as the last character .. focus does not switch until pressed twice ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Add 'tabGuard: false' config to your window. It will fix this small bug, but you will lose the circular tab navigation. Your window will be as normal floatable panel.

Comment: what is tabGuard for in window?

Comment: it's working in fiddle ... but would like to have some explanation of what is going on and why. Is there any other way to implement custom tab key press jumping from field to field ?

Comment: I think tabGuard was added to prevent focusing of the elements behind window. When your window hides the main screen, the elements in may screen must not be focusable. For example user can focus some buttons behind the popup and click them with tab or enter key.

Comment: To implement custom tab navigation your can use 'tabIndex' peroperty (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-tabIndex).

Comment: I've been looking at sources and understood what's it all about. Just not sure yet how to fix it. If I can't find a solution to make this work (simple fix) I'll implement custom tab indexing manager ... don't see any other way.

Comment: You can also use (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html#event-specialkey) event to catch the tab keypress and move the focus to another element..

Comment: I found out that if I use another field after textarea field, tab works fine ...

Comment: I have also noticed that.